# wifi can connect, dns works, no internet

Tags: wireless, internet

For a couple of months now, I've been having problems with my wifi connection. I can connect to the router, DNS seems to work, but I have no internet. The strange thing about this is that it happens at random times and resolves itself equally randomly (several times a day). I have no idea what is going on.

If you need more info, please let me know. Any help would be immensely appreciated!

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic


tomas@Yoga:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-47-generic


tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo lspci -vn
...
01:00.0 0280: 14e4:43b1 (rev 03)
        Subsystem: 17aa:0623
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Memory at c1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Memory at c1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 2c-33-00-ff-ff-00-00-01
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: bcma, wl


tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TelenetWiFree
[connection]
id=TelenetWiFree
uuid=3c973a3d-48fe-4aee-b78c-0323eb02bb7c
type=wifi
permissions=user:kubuntu:;

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=TelenetWiFree

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=t195917
password=*****************
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 03
       serial: 2c:33:7a:f0:df:e9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=10.127.226.93 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1200000-c1207fff memory:c1000000-c11fffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:a1:8d:f4
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:a1:8d:f4
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s


tomas@Yoga:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
8: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

---

In response to vidarlo . Internet is working at the moment, I will try these commands again when it is not.

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ ip route
default via 10.127.128.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.127.128.0/17 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.127.205.52 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 

tomas@Yoga:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:33:7a:f0:df:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                                                         
    inet 10.127.205.52/17 brd 10.127.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0                                                                         
       valid_lft 532sec preferred_lft 532sec                                                                                                                   
    inet6 fe80::de0e:ee8a:956d:330f/64 scope link noprefixroute                                                                                                
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                                                 
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                                       
    link/ether 52:54:00:a1:8d:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                                                         
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0                                                                                              
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                                                 
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                                  
    link/ether 52:54:00:a1:8d:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                                                         

tomas@Yoga:~$ ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=192 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=121 time=24.7 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.700/108.760/192.821/84.061 ms
```

Internet not working:

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ ip route
default via 10.123.128.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.123.128.0/17 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.123.215.188 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 

tomas@Yoga:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                                                                                                                             
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                                                 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host                                                                                                                                   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                                                 
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000                                                          
    link/ether 2c:33:7a:f0:df:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                                                         
    inet 10.123.215.188/17 brd 10.123.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0                                                                        
       valid_lft 459sec preferred_lft 459sec                                                                                                                   
    inet6 fe80::de0e:ee8a:956d:330f/64 scope link noprefixroute                                                                                                
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                                                 
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                                       
    link/ether 52:54:00:a1:8d:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                                                         
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0                                                                                              
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                                                 
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                                  
    link/ether 52:54:00:a1:8d:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                                                         

tomas@Yoga:~$ ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1023ms
```

To show that DNS is working:

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches 
[sudo] wachtwoord voor tomas:                                                                                                                                  
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo systemd-resolve --statistics 
DNSSEC supported by current servers: no                                                                                                                        

Transactions
Current Transactions: 0
  Total Transactions: 3313

Cache
  Current Cache Size: 5
          Cache Hits: 365
        Cache Misses: 135

DNSSEC Verdicts
              Secure: 0
            Insecure: 0
               Bogus: 0
       Indeterminate: 0
tomas@Yoga:~$ ping -c 2 belgium.be
PING belgium.be (193.191.245.244) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- belgium.be ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1022ms
```

Does this tell you something?

---

In response to Marmayogi . Internet is working at the moment, I made the changes to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and will reboot after I've had my dose of internet...

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ echo "# blacklisting ideapad_wlan ......" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf                                                           
[sudo] wachtwoord voor tomas:                                                                                                                                  
# blacklisting ideapad_wlan ......                                                                                                                             
tomas@Yoga:~$ echo "blacklist ideapad_wlan" | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf                                                  
blacklist ideapad_wlan                                                                                                                                         
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo tail /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
...
# blacklisting ideapad_wlan ......
blacklist ideapad_wlan
```

Rebooting now.

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo reboot
```

Internet is working, I will check if it drops again...

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
[sudo] wachtwoord voor tomas: 
tomas@Yoga:~$
```

Internet is not working anymore. Should I remove the ideapad blacklist? Can you explain why you gave that suggestion? Any other suggestions?

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo nmcli device
[sudo] wachtwoord voor tomas: 
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION    
wlp1s0      wifi      verbonden  TelenetWiFree 
virbr0      bridge    verbonden  virbr0        
lo          loopback  onbeheerd  --            
virbr0-nic  tun       onbeheerd  --            
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan      brcmwl-0          unblocked unblocked
 6 bluetooth hci0              unblocked unblocked
```

No output for systemctl restart ... :

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
tomas@Yoga:~$
```

---

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ tail -n2  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# blacklisting ideapad_wlan ......
blacklist ideapad_laptop
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo reboot
```

...

```
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
[sudo] wachtwoord voor tomas:
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo nmcli device
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE                     CONNECTION
virbr0      bridge    verbonden                 virbr0
wlp1s0      wifi      verbinden (configureren)  TelenetWiFree
lo          loopback  onbeheerd                 --
virbr0-nic  tun       onbeheerd                 --
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE        SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0     unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      brcmwl-0 unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0     unblocked unblocked
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ip route`, `ip a` and `ping -c 2 8.8.8.8` as well?

Comment: Issue commands: 1. `echo "# blacklisting ideapad_wlan ......" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and 2. `echo "blacklist ideapad_wlan" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. **Reboot the system**. Issue command `sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service` and observe for any output. If no output then `blacklisting` was  successful. Now you try to connect to internet.

Comment: @Marmayogi, Tried your suggestion, it didn't work. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @vidarlo I updated the question with your commands, both with and without working internet connection.

Comment: @Tomas, please try this command: `rfkill unblock all` and **Reboot**. See Wi-Fi connects.

Comment: `tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo reboot`
`tomas@Yoga:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no`
Is it normal that ideapad_wlan is still in there, we disabled that module, didn't we?

Comment: @Marmayogi Still nothing...

Comment: `ideapad_wlan` is still not blacklisted? I can see clearly from the output of `rfkill list` command from your previous comment. **That is why the solution offered did not work**. In fact, I was really surprised with that news. As long as it is present, your Wi-Fi will never work with stability because it always clashes with `wlp1s0` and tries to block it! BTW, please paste output of the command `nmcli device` and `rfkill`  (only `rfkill` nothing else).  Did you issue the command: `sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service` after rebooting upon blacklisting? what was the output?

Comment: @Marmayogi see question above for your new commands...

Comment: Please edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file and change `blacklist ideapad_wlan` to `blacklist ideapad_laptop`. **Reboot the system**. Issue command `sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service` and observe for any output. If no output then blacklisting was successful. Please post output of `nmcli device` and `rfkill` commands. @Tomas, now you try to connect to internet.

Comment: @Marmayogi Now ideapad_... have disappeared from rfkill output, see above. For the moment internet is working. Will let you know in a day or so if it stays that way (or maybe a couple of hours if it doesn't).

Comment: @Marmayogi
It is working much better now, less frequent drops of my internet connection. But I noticed something else, which you can't help me with: I'm using a friend's account on my neighbour's router (these telenet routers all have an open channel for customers to use while not at home). When both my laptop and my cellphone are connected it happens that one or the other (or both) can't connect to the internet. So I suppose the 'free' slots are filled at that time. I have no access to the router so, I guess this is as far as we will get.
Thanks a lot for all your help!